# sql query to return records from two columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table  with id (PK), type, sub-type

| id | type | sub-type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | address1 | type1 |
| 2 | address1 | type2 |
| 3 | address2 | type1 |
| 4 | address2 | type 3 |
| 5 | address1 | type3 |

I want my query to return all values where address1 is IN type1, type3
and address2 with type1

```
select * from information e  where e.type IN (SELECT type  from information ev where ev.type = 'address1' AND `sub-type` IN ('type1', 'type3') )
```

But this does not return me type1, type3 and I am not able to build further with this query for both types

Comment: `Group By` Could be the fruitful solution ,Also  Your Table structure is a bit unclear If you can please share the screenshot of the database you have

Comment: @PunitGajjar I have edited my question to better represent the table structure
Let me look into how can I use Group By

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM information e  
WHERE (e.type = 'address1' AND `sub-type` IN ('type1', 'type3'))
   OR (e.type = 'address2' AND `sub-type` = 'type1')
```